# Looking for historical daily quotes for USD

Tags: data-request, economics

I am trying to find USD currency rate to the Germand Mark, "Deutsche Mark" (DM) back till 1959. The "Deutsche Mark is the ancestor of the euro. The data should be daily. OHLC is super, but just Close would be good enough.

If needed i can pay a smaller sum. Really need this data for testing some models! Please help!

Greetings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for your answer. I found the data now online on the website of the german Bundesbank (german federal reserve):

https://www.bundesbank.de/Navigation/DE/Statistiken/Zeitreihen_Datenbanken/Aussenwirtschaft/aussenwirtschaft_node.html

You can pick resolution from yearly, to monthly to even daily back till 1953!

hope that helps...

Answer (score 2):

You can find the data as plain text on the [Federal Reserve's website](https://www.federalreserve.gov/releases/H10/hist/dat89_ge.txt). There are several currencies to choose from. The downside is that it only goes back to 1971.

#### Federal Reserve

https://www.federalreserve.gov/releases/H10/hist/thru89.htm

#### Alternative source

https://research.stlouisfed.org/fred2/data/EXGEUS.txt

#### New York Federal Reserve

The New York Fed has historical data back only to 1983
https://apps.newyorkfed.org

For daily data prior to 1973 you'd have to go to paper archives in Frankfurt because they aren't available online. If you manage to collect the older data please consider making it public.

Here are the yearly averages from 1915-1969
http://www.history.ucsb.edu/faculty/marcuse/projects/currency.htm